# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPExercise\go4shop\header.php as

```
php require("bar.php");
echo "<hr />";
if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == T RUE) {
    echo "Logged in as <strong>".$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']."</strong>[<a href=" & quot;.$config_basedir. & quot;
    logout.php ">logout</a>]";
} else {
    echo "<a href=" & quot;.$config_basedir. & quot;
    login.php ">Login</a>";
}
```

Comment: Fix your code display/formatting first. Are there really `&quot;`'s ?

Comment: People, __stop upvoting everything that has negative score__. It only negates the purpose of voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code. Use the below code:

```
php require("bar.php");
echo "<hr/>";
if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'])) {
    echo "Logged in as <strong>".$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']."</strong>[<a href='".$config_basedir."logout.php'>logout</a>]";
} else {
    echo "<a href='".$config_basedir."login.php'>Login</a>";
}
```

Remove the `&quot;` from the code. And make the code workable.

Comment: `T RUE` should be `TRUE`

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya ok Bindiya ji. Have done. Thanks :)

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ 

One more question please >>
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPExercise\go4shop\bar.php on line 5 <br/>

<code>echo '<a id="" href=' . $config_basedir. "/products.php?id=" . $catrow. ">". $catrow['name'] . "</a>";</code>

Comment: @HakeemIbnFaisal your code should be this: `<a id="" href=' . $config_basedir. "/products.php?id=" . $catrow['id']. "'>". $catrow['name'] . "</a>"`.

Comment: @HakeemIbnFaisal this should be `$catrow['id']` not `$catrow`.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ Ok great. very appreciated :)